# How to get reid of nested for loop to speed up my programe?

Tags: matlab

I have nested forloop in matlab and I'm runnig it for very large data sets.

I was wondering how can I get rid of for loops and make my code faster.

Here is my code:

```
 for p=1:length(Gamma)
     %disp(p)
     gamma=Gamma(p)
     for Fold=1:size(Fold_indices,2)
     x_Train=x(logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);

     Y_Train=y(logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:Num_Tasks);


     x_Test=x(~logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:end);
     Y_Test=y(~logical(Fold_indices(:,Fold)),1:Num_Tasks);
     coff = proxgrad(x_Train,Y_Train,MAX_ITR,lambda,gamma,Bind,epsilon);

     tmp(Fold,1:end)=sum((x_Test*coff-Y_Test).^2) ./ size(x_Test,1);
     end
     In_Fold_Error{1,p}=tmp;

 end
```

**x,y** are matrices and *proxgrad* is  function. I would appreciate any help .

Comment: Are `proxgrad`, `x`, `y`, arrays or functions? If they are functions, an optimization is not possible without knowing what these are doing.

Comment: x, y are matrices and proxgrad is a function